# React with Gatsby and Bulma - Columns are not horizontal

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, bulma

I'm new to Bulma and I just copy & pasted from a tutorial but, I can't get the horizontal columns.

```
<Fragment>
          <Level mobile renderAs="nav">
            <Level.Item textAlignment="centered">
              <div>
                <p className="heading">tweets</p>
                <Heading renderAs="p">3,456</Heading>
              </div>
            </Level.Item>
            <Level.Item textAlignment="centered">
              <div>
                <p className="heading">following</p>
                <Heading renderAs="p">123</Heading>
              </div>
            </Level.Item>
            <Level.Item textAlignment="centered">
              <div>
                <p className="heading">followers</p>
                <Heading renderAs="p">456K</Heading>
              </div>
            </Level.Item>
            <Level.Item textAlignment="centered">
              <div>
                <p className="heading">likes</p>
                <Heading renderAs="p">789</Heading>
              </div>
            </Level.Item>
          </Level>
        </Fragment>
```

I just put it into a Fragment. It's supposed to work but it doesn't. Any idea?
thanks

Comment: you need to enable sass in your gatsby config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Gatsby's documentation for Bulma](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/bulma/) shows:

> For starters, lets install all the required packages we’re going to
> need.
> `yarn add bulma node-sass gatsby-plugin-sass`
>
> Then add the gatsby-plugin-sass in to `gatsby-config.js`.

You need to add and enable `gatsby-plugin-sass`. Once you've installed the packages and dependencies, add the following line to your `gatsby-config.js`:

```
plugins: [`gatsby-plugin-sass`],
```

Resources:

- https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/with-node-sass/
- https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/bulma/

Comment: I'm using react-boostarp but I'll try it asap. thanks